# Notification using AWS SNS for Android. Always getting message with "default" string prefix

Tags: php, android, amazon-web-services, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send notification from SNS to Android app using FCM API key and token.

On my webapp, I am using PHP and calling publish function on snsClient as below -

```
$snsClient->publish(array('Message' => 'hello',
                         'TargetArn' => $endpointArn)
                    );
```

On my Android application side, I am trying to listen for message by overriding `onMessageReceived` of `FirebaseMessagingService` class like below -

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    // Check if message contains a data payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());

    // Check if message contains a notification payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        String msgReceived = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
        Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + msgReceived);
        // pass on message to other function for further processing
        sendNotification(msgReceived);
    }
}
```

As soon as I run php, onMessageReceived of Android app gets hit but I always get `remoteMessage.getNotification()` as `null` and `{default=hello}` as return value of getData()!

I tried to send message from AWS SNS console. When I send plain text I get same `{default=hello}` string. If I use *JSON message generator* option present in AWS SNS console, it generates string

```
{"GCM": "{ \"data\": { \"message\": \"hello\" } }"}
```

and when I send this, I get proper message in getData of Android app. However getNotification still returns null.

Can someone help in understanding -

1. why `default` is getting added to my message (`hello` in this case)
   if I send plain text.
2. how to generate `{"GCM": "{ \"data\": {\"message\": \"hello\" } }"}` for `hello` message string in php. `json_encode` does not generate this string.
3. how to insert notification part to `hello` so `getNotification` in Android app does not return `null`.